# I need to count the number of cells that say something from another workbook

Tags: google-sheets

I’m creating a spreadsheet on google sheets and need to count how many cells contain certain information on another workbook, any ideas on what formula I should use? I’ve tried combining countif and importrange but can’t seem to get it to work.

It would also be really useful if I could get the formula to match the date at the top of the column that I’m referencing to the date of the column on the spreadsheet I’m creating

This is the last formula I tried:
=Countif(importrange(link,”Resource Planner 2021!HL:HL”),"<>Day Off")

Comment: If you run just IMPORTRANGE() alone, does it pull in the correct dataset?

Comment: Not as yet but I’ve just found out the document I’m referencing is an excel import

Answer (score 0):

You could use QUERY and feed it the IMPORTRANGE as data. Then use something like `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(link;”Resource Planner 2021!HL:HL”);"select Sum(ColX) where ColX = "Day Off"";1)`

In case you could provide a example or copy of the sheet in question I could try to make a more specific sugestion.